# SQL SELECT Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a very simple table that has businesses and a column of `DisplayBiz = varchar(1)` that is either Y or N...  I want a script to extract data from the database first all the "Y" and then then all the "N" for a total of ten and I want them ordered by business name..

Is there a way to do this? I am assuming it would be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 MemberID,
BizName
ORDER BY BizType
```

but this doesn't take into consideration the DisplayBiz column

Any ideas?

Many thanks..!

Comment: If that column is always just 1 character long - make it a `CHAR(1)` and save yourself the 2-byte overhead for the VARCHAR part (which really doesn't come into play here) ....

Comment: +1 @marc_s - pet peeve of mine as well to see `varchar(anything less than 4)`

Comment: Why not use a bit/boolean column instead?

Comment: These techniques although good do not give me alphabetical ordering for the business names.  Is there a way to extract the yes's first and then the no's and combine the 2 datasets and then order them..?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want the top 10 rows where DisplayBiz = 'Y' and then the top 10 rows where DisplayBiz = 'N', so 20 row altogether? Otherwise, if there are more than 10 rows where DisplayBiz = 'Y', how do you expect to get any with 'N' in the result? Also, how does the ORDER BY BizType fit in? Maybe you could show some sample data and desired results, then there will be less guessing.

Comment: There could be 3 Yes's in the database  and I want to fill the other 7 places with No's with a total of ten.. If there are 12 Yes's in the database I want to just display the first 10..

Comment: So why is ORDER BY BizType in the question? Is BizType a column? What is its data type and how does that ordering relate to the ordering by Y/N and then alphabetical by business name? Again, some sample data and the ordering you want to see in the result will be a lot more helpful than describing what you want to see in paragraph form.

Comment: BizType is another column varchar(200) that contains: Advertiser or Painter for example.. that is the column I want in alphabetical order I dont want ordering by Y/N

Comment: Can this be done... by UNION?

Comment: You are still being confusing. Above you say you want to order by business name, then you want to order by biz type, now you no longer care about ordering by Y/N. Please, for everyone's sanity, STOP DESCRIBING what you want and SHOW us.

Answer (score 3):

You can add more than one column in the ORDER BY clause :

```
-- ...
ORDER BY DisplayBiz DESC, BizType
```

Which would put Y rows first, then N rows.

Answer (score 2):

This will get the first 10 alphabetical BizNames that have a 'Y' for DisplayBiz. If there are less than 10, it will start over at A for those with 'N'...

```
SELECT TOP 10 MemberID, BizName, DisplayBiz
    FROM dbo.table
    ORDER BY 
       CASE WHEN DisplayBiz = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
       BizName;
```

You could also use:

```
ORDER BY 
    DisplayBiz DESC,
    BizName;
```

But I prefer the `CASE` - while more code, you're not taking advantage of the English spelling of Y/N. Seems more proper to be explicit.